# Scrolling at the end of a page in selenium java automated testing on Mac OS

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I tried both the code below to go at the end of a page but it is not scrolling down.Is it anything to do with chrome browser on Mac?

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,713)", ""); Thread.sleep(1000); Long height=(Long) js.executeScript("return document.body.scrollHeight");

      driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(Keys.END);
```

Comment: Can you share URL? Or page source code at least. If you get any exception, post your output as well.

Comment: the page is long I can't post it here.URL require login and hence I can't share it

Comment: @pbburgr there is no exception

Answer (score 1):

After lot of trial and error now I could solve this issue.Eventhough I didn't understand the logic behind this, posting the answer here might be useful for somebody else.

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(Keys.END);

this code didn't work for me ,but I was trying with a while loop based on page height and above code ,manually clicked on the screen and I could. see that the screen scrolling down.So I just added a code to click on one of the element in the page prior to executing the above code and it works.Felt strange but it is working now.

Comment: Lost focus may be a bug in browser. Check for updates of your browser and it's driver. Let me guess, you are using Firefox.

Comment: No. chrome & Mac OS